# Custom views inside canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, view

I want to create a GUI in android where I want to achieve the following :-
1) Drag and connect components(image view) to an custom view.

2) While the connection has been achieved the component and the custom view has to be connected using a bezier curve.

3) When I move the connected component around (drag and move), the connected line should expand/contract accordingly. (ie, This cannot be a static image, it needs to be drawn.)

Please provide me with some guidelines to achieve the same.

The challenge is that to draw the connection line I have to use a canvas, but canvas doesnot allow custom views/ image views inside it.

Comment: so just use `canvas.DrawBitmap` instead of the ImageView

Comment: @Budius, I need to use a custom view as well, the components are connected to this custom view, how to solve this. Do you think I can do this with frame layout or some thing?