# Flickering while using surface view to draw frame by frame bitmap

Tags: android, gif, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I am using surface view to render frames after extracted from video, the problem is that there is a flickering effect while rendering, the origin video was smooth, I play the frames in ImageViewer and hold on press NEXT key to switch next and next it was smooth too, only flicker after render them in SurfaceView.

the problem is I have a period between frames drawing, because I want to control the playing frame rate, make it slower or faster via user's choice, once I give up the delay drawing the problem gone, but that's no my intention, I need to make them delay.

I understand that this is due to double/triple buffering problem, even though I went through many posts, including turn to use GLSurfaceView to render, also drawBitmap twice intent to keep front-buffer and back-buffer align, it doesn't help to fix this problem.

I found this [Flickering while using surface view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29348022/1294681) post, and try all the solution-like mention inside, but it's not work, the accepted answer mention about dirty rect, remind me to update every pixels if call `lockCanvas()` without rect specified, but I think I already draw the whole bitmap in the next, imply I updated every pixels, so I get not idea of this.

below are the code and the problem's gif, please take a look at my code and help me get this fixed.

```kotlin
class CustomView(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?
) : SurfaceView(context, attrs), Runnable {
    private var animationThread: Thread? = null

    @Volatile private var running = false
    private var frameList: List<BitmapFrame1>? = null
    private var index = 0

    fun start(frameList: List<BitmapFrame1>) {
        if (running) return
        running = true
        index = 0
        this.frameList = frameList
        animationThread = Thread(this).apply {
            start()
        }
    }

    override fun run() {
        val surHolder = holder
        var nextFrameTimeMs = 0L
        while (running) {
            if (!surHolder.surface.isValid) continue
            if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() >= nextFrameTimeMs) {
                val currentFrame = frameList!!.getOrNull(++index)
                if (currentFrame == null) {
                    running = false
                } else {
                    val canvas = surHolder.lockCanvas()
                    canvas.drawBitmap(currentFrame.bitmap, 0f, 0f, Paint())
                    val drawTimestamp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
                    surHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                    nextFrameTimeMs = drawTimestamp + currentFrame.delayMs
                }
            } else {
                // have tried to draw the current frame again before delay time's up,
                // but not effect
                val currentFrame = frameList!![index]
                val canvas = surHolder.lockCanvas()
                canvas.drawBitmap(currentFrame.bitmap, 0f, 0f, Paint())
                surHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: flicker effect]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Choreographer and not lock Canvas in "random" moment (this wrong moment could occurs when Surface is swapping from one buffer to another and the Bitmap/Texture is uploaded on wrong buffer) but only after a Choreographer callback event.
When this event occurs it's guaranteed that the next frame is uploaded on the right buffer and rendered well in next Drawing call.

```
Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(new Callback(){
    @Override
    public doFrame(final long frameTimeNanos) {
        surHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(currentFrame.bitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
        surHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
});
```

So if you want to slow down rendering you need to "queue" requests using an Handler and send a delayed Message to trigger the drawing procedure (below it's pseudo code):

```
private Handler mHandler;
private final Choreographer.Callback mCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public doFrame(final long frameTimeNanos) {
        surHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(currentFrame.bitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
        surHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

public void prepareHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new method() {
        @Override
        private void handleMessage(@NonNull final Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1234: {
                    Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(mCallback);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void postponeDraw(final long millis) {
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1234, 500/*milliseconds*/);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I try your code, but the problem still

Comment: Please append your code (in the question) using my suggestion because your implementation COULD be the issue.

Comment: hi, the problem was fixed, it is a bug about re-arrange the frame list, messed the order a little bit, I use the code I post in the question was work after fix that, thank you for paying attention on this, and apologize

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement [`Choreographer.FrameCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.FrameCallback) to synchronize the device's frame rate apart from playing frame rate.

Some good samples are Google's [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika). Here is a comment from [RecordFBOActivity.java](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java):

> We use Choreographer so our animation matches vsync, and a separate
> rendering thread to keep the heavy lifting off of the UI thread.
> Ideally we'd let the render thread receive the Choreographer events
> directly, but that appears to be creating a permanent JNI global
> reference to the render thread object, preventing it from being
> garbage collected (which, in turn, causes the Activity to be
> retained).  So instead we receive the vsync on the UI thread and
> forward it.

They made the RenderThread as a Looper thread. Also prepared a Handler for the thread. Implementing `Choreographer.FrameCallback` to the SurfaceView, they forward `doFrame` callback to RenderThread by posting a Handler message.

Comment: Grafika was too complicated to fetch the key code for me, anyway, use FrameCallback probably can't  help depends on emandt's answer